# Ansible - password containing one double quote is not parsed correctly

Tags: passwords, ansible, escaping

The password of one of my servers contains a double quote, e.g. `dga"fddf`.
I've tried both assignments below in inventory.ini file

- `ansible_ssh_pass=dga\"fddf`
- `ansible_ssh_pass='dga"fddf'`

and I have debug msg in my playbook

```
 debug:
  msg: "ansible_ssh_pass: {{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"
```

the result from both assignements are the same

> "msg": "ansible_ssh_pass: dga\"fddf"

while the expected value is dga"fddf. How can I preserve the double quote literally in the string ?

Comment: Don't use a password with a quotation mark inside. Problem solved.

Comment: The output `"ansible_ssh_pass": "pass\"word"` is correct, because the `"` must be quoted in the json. Is the password working correct?

Comment: @JGK you are right, the problem is with the server, it simply ignore the double quote in the password, confusingly, it allows user to set password to a string containing double quote, however, during login, user need to remove all the double quotes